# Update on select count using eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have an eloquent query which returns the 10 most frequently found names in a table.

```
$topPeople = $model
    ->select(['name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')])
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

This works fine for returning results but I want to update these records rather than return the data. When I use update instead of get;

```
$model
    ->select(['name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')])
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->update(['popular' => 1]);
```

I get the error;

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 'order clause'

What is an efficient way of updating the `popular` field in these records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the ids, then use those to perform the update. Here's an example using your code, slightly changed:

```
$topPeople = SomeModel
    ->select(['id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')])
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->pluck('id');

SomeModel::whereIn('id', $topPeople)->update(['popular' => 1]);
```

Comment: pluck! Thats the functionality I was looking for, thank you